# PHP mcrypt error in Centos 7

Tags: php, centos

Can anyone shed light on this yum issue? Does yum just need an update touse these RPMs? If so is it available officially for rhel6.1 yet?

```
[root@pstagetest yum.repos.d]# yum install php-pecl-igbinary Loaded plugins: changelog, downloadonly, product-id, subscription-manager     Updating Red Hat repositories. Setting up Install Process Resolving Dependencies    

--> Running transaction check

---> Package php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64 0:1.1.1-2.el6.remi will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.1-2.el6.remi.x86_64

--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.1-2.el6.remi.x86_64

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.1-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (repo) Requires: php(api) = 20090626-x86-64 Installed: php-common-5.3.9-1.el6.remi    .x86_64 (@repo) php(api) = 20090626 php(api) = 20090626-x86-64    

Error: Package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.1-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (repo) Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626-x86-64 Installed: php-common-5.3.9-1.el6    .remi.x86_64 (@repo) php(zend-abi) = 20090626 php(zend-abi) = 20090626-x86-64    

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and more suited for http://serverfault.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. remove old epel repo
2. remove all package of php
3. search php package by yum list installed | grep php
4. yum remove pacakge name
5. download new epel http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm
6. rpm -Uvh epel-release*
7. then install php
8. Install php-mcrypt